# Unknown class AVPlayerViewController in Interface builder file

Tags: avfoundation, uistoryboard, xcode9, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I am adding AVPlayerViewController in storyboard, but when I run the app I get this error iOS device or simulator.

```
Unknown class AVPlayerViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Maybe you have added **AVPlayerViewController** wrong way. you can check this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was I was using @import AVKit in the code but there wasn't a single line in the code that initialized AVPlayerViewController, so effectively AVKit was not imported at runtime which caused warning of unknown class when loading Xib containing AVPlayerViewController.